# Should Plan cost be less than 100?

Tags: oracle, performance, sql-execution-plan, sql-optimization

I know lesser the cost faster will be query. But recently i came  across the statement that cost should always be less than 100 . Is that true ?

As per my understanding cost is proportioal to (IO operation/CPU usage/network resources used). Which means when i say cost is high ,any/all of  these three operations i.e IO operation/CPU usage/network resources  usage can be high . Is that correct ?

Comment: No that statement is complete and utter nonsense!  Cost only makes sense in comparing one plan with another for the same query. A cost of 10,000,000 might be quite acceptable for some query that returns a huge result set.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Ismy understanding on Cost  correct ?

Comment: Also as you said "Cost only makes sense in comparing one plan with another for the same query", it means there is nothing wrong in having cost in thousands. It means we should try to bring it low if possible ?

Comment: Yes, all else being equal, and if your database stats are accurate enough, a plan with a low cost should perform better than a plan with a high cost.  Probably!

Answer (score 3):

A cost should be accurate.  Unless we're talking about examining different plans for the same query from a 10053 trace, worry far more about accuracy rather than whether a cost is low or high.

If you have a query that is hitting millions of rows and performing a bunch of aggregates, a plan with a cost of 10 is likely to be highly inefficient.  Logically, you know that the query is going to be pretty expensive.  If the optimizer thinks that the query is very cheap, that almost guarantees that your statistics are inaccurate.  If your statistics are inaccurate, that means that the optimizer is going to pick a plan that is less efficient than it should be.  Personally, I wouldn't be surprised if I've identified more queries that needed attention by noticing a cost that is way too low than by noticing a cost that is way too high.

Picking any sort of cut-off for cost is ridiculous.  If you know that every query is going to be part of an OLTP application that fetches a few dozen rows, it might make sense to take a second look at a plan with a cost in the thousands to see if the optimizer picked a bad plan because of invalid statistics.  But very, very few systems only have that very specific sort of OLTP query-- most systems have a miss of very cheap queries that return a row or two and more expensive queries that read and aggregate larger numbers of rows.  Creating any sort of cap tends to lead developers to do stupid things-- putting "cheap" queries inside a loop rather than writing an "expensive" join may mean that all your queries have low cost but that your entire system runs much less efficiently than it could.

Comment: Thanks Justin. you said "a plan with a cost of 10 is likely to be highly inefficient" Does it means plan efficiency depends on other parameters too apart from cost ?

Comment: Also you said "If the optimizer thinks that the query is very cheap, that almost guarantees that your statistics are inaccurate" I am not sure what does statistics mean here ?